# low variables / playa / matrix

Tags: matrix, playa, low-variables

I'm stuck on something that will probably be very easy to resolve but I just don't see it anymore.

I'm using low variable to create the content of a carousel slider. For each slider the information is added in a matrix row. At the end of each row I created a playa field which fetches data from two channels to retrieve their title.

The carousel works very well and the different row's are added to the carousel and I can also retrieve the title from the playa field.

Now the issue I have is that per matrix row iteration playa loops through the total row's which results in that I get all the titles on every slide of the carousel.
I would like to only get the title of the playa field defined in the matrix row of my current iteration.

It's probably a scripting error or I'm not using the tags how they should be used, so if somebody could have a peak that would be great.

Here below you'll find some screenshots.

thx,
Claudio

```
<div id="sliderBlock">
    <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
    {exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_hp_car"}
        <li><!--<a href="http://www.google.com">-->
                {exp:ce_img:single src="{hp_car_item_img}" width="781" height="443" alt="{hp_car_item_title}" crop="yes"}
            <!--</a>...-->

            {if hp_car_item_title != ""}
            <div class="flex-caption">
                {exp:playa:children var="playa_test" var_prefix="hpcar" }<h2>{hpcar:title}</h2>{/exp:playa:children}
                {if hp_car_item_type == "Exhibition"}<p class="date">{hp_car_item_start_date}  -  {hp_car_item_end_date}</p>{/if}
                <p class="description">{hp_car_item_intro}</p>
                <p class="author">{hp_car_item_credits}</p>
                <p class="imgHeader"><img src="image/backgroundTransparant.png" /></p>
            </div>
            {/if}
        </li>
    {/exp:low_variables:pair}
    </ul>

    <div id="clearFloat"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I found a solution but I will post it tomorrow because apparently I cannot answer my own question within 8 hours of posting it because my reputation score is below 10.

Answer (score 1):

ok now I found it! :D

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="my_matrix"}
    {exp:playa:children var="pl"}

        {if {my_matrix:row_count} == {pl:count}}

             <h2>{pl:title}</h2>

        {/if}

    {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```